# binarySearch implementation issues

Tags: java, binary-search

When I tried to write the following line:

```
int foundIndex = Collections.<K>binarySearch(keys, key);
```

it shows the error: **The parameterized method `<K>binarySearch(List<? extends Comparable<? super K>>, K)` of type 
 `Collections` is not applicable for the arguments `(List<K>, K)`**

What does the above error mean and what did I do wrong in my code?

```
    // Comparator used to sort elements; may be null if elements are Comparable
    public final Comparator<K> cmp;  


    {
        super(new ArrayList<K>(), new ArrayList<V>());
        cmp = new MyComparator<K>();
    }

    // Use the given comparator to sort the keys

        //super(new ArrayList<K>(), new ArrayList<V>());
        this.cmp = cmp;
    }


    {
        if(!(key instanceof Comparable) && cmp == null)
            throw new RuntimeException("The key is not instance of Comparable or comparator object is null");
    }

    public int indexOf(K key) 
    {
        int foundIndex = Collections.<K>binarySearch(keys, key);

        return foundIndex;
    }

    public int compareTo(K otherKey) 
    {
        int result = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < keys.size(); i++)
        {
            result = ((Comparable<K>) keys.get(i)).compareTo(otherKey);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

MyComparator class

```
import java.util.Comparator;



    @Override
    public int compare(K key1, K key2)
    {
        return -1;
    }

}
```

Comment: where is `keys` declared?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `FastGetListMM<K, V>` is implementing `Comparable<K>` but that `Collections.<K>binarySearch(list, value)` is expecting a *list* of `Comparable<K>`.

It is `K` that should implement `Comparable<K>`, not `FastGetListMM`. If you want to use `Collections.<K>binarySearch(keys, key)` you need `FastGetListMM` to implement `List<Comparable<K>>` and not `Comparable<K>` - and make sure that all the items in `FastGetListMM` are arranged in ascending order.

Answer (score 0):

To use that implementation of binary search you need `K` to implement comparable there is another function that receives the comparable itself. In your case you need to call `Collections.<K>binarySearch(keys, key, new MyComparator());`